# relative time in redux reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have some data with datetime fields , i want to show the relative date time using momentJS `fromNow()`. However after the initial load it shows timestamp as `a few seconds ago`. But this will not be updated until a next state change triggered. *Is it a good practice* to keep another state in the state-tree & control via a timer function `setInterval` in `componentDidUpdate`?

```
render()
{
   // get the new prop value here which triggered from a setInterval -> action -> reducer -> state change -> propagate to connected components
   const text = comment.get('text');
   const dateTime = moment(comment.get('dateTime')).fromNow();
   return (
     // add the new prop into the component
     <div key={id}>
        <Comment
         text = {text}
         dateTime = {dateTime}
     </div>
}
```

Comment: rule of thumb => if you can calculate it from props in render time without much resource, then don't put it into state.

Comment: Yup, that's right but question is how to re-render after some time to show the timestamps in a relative manner. When it renders second time, it will calculate the relative time from props as per this line `moment(comment.get('dateTime')).fromNow();`

Comment: I agree with @harun, and you can still keep your solution. Just instead of putting the resulted text from `moment` in your redux state, I would put in the local component state, and make it update every some interval internally, without bothering the rest of the system.

Comment: @MotiAzu yes, I am not going to keep text from moment to redux state.. I may generate a random number from `setInterval` and keep that in the state to do re-render. I guess I can proceed this way :)

Comment: It's a VERY hackish way to go about it, since this state is only used for you to re-render. A local component state is a lot more reasonable in my opinion

Comment: @MotiAzu Yup agree with u. I was thinking abt local component state initially. But when there are multiple components involved, i need to pass this to all children as props(gets messy) or maintain separate timers(may not be a good idea).

Comment: How about a component that just displays time? it takes timestamp and converts with `moment.js`, and you only use this component to show time. It can manage it's own interval and state, and you can pass style into it so it will be very easy to reuse

Comment: Awesome.. I think it should go in the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scribbled down a component that takes an epoch time timestamp and display a momentjs text for it.
The text is updates via inner component state every 300ms which you can change however you'd like.

You can notice on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01est081/1/), every new text is logged in the console. After 45 seconds you should see the text change from "a few seconds ago" to "a minute ago".

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/01est081/1/), this is the code:

```
var MomentTime = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {text: ""};
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this._updateMomentText();
    this.interval = setInterval(this._updateMomentText, 300);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },

  _updateMomentText: function() {
    var text = moment(this.props.timestamp).fromNow()
    console.log(text)
    if(text !== this.state.text) {
        this.setState({text: text});
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.state.text}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MomentTime timestamp={new Date().getTime()} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Though it is a good solution, I think, this is creating a performance issue. Since it attaches timer to all the `MomentTime` components, browser load will just shoot up. When we have 100's of such components, it will cause significant responsiveness issues. What do u think?

Comment: It doesn't update unless moment returns a different text. But if you have this many of these, I would simply suggest you change the 300ms interval to 30 seconds (or something in that area). Since this text doesn't change every second, this is probably very reasonable and shouldn't be hard on your app.